# Логический оператор ||

Tags: javascript, операторы

Суть задачи: дана строка, в ней нужно просуммировать все гласные

```
        function getCount(str){
        var vowelsCount = 0;
        var array = [];
        array = str.split("");
        for (var s=0;s<array.length;s++){
            if(array[s] === "a"/*||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u"*/){
                vowelsCount += +1;
            }
        }
        //a, e, i, o, u,
        return vowelsCount;

    }
    console.log(getCount("abracadabra"));
    console.log(getCount("abcdu"));
```

Вопрос почему не срабатывает оператор ||    P.S. "Я его закомментировал"

Comment: Условие `array[s] === "a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u"` равносильно условию `array[s] === ("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")`, что в свою очередь равносильно условию `array[s] === "a"`.

Comment: @Yaant Неправда – будь это так, то не работали бы условия вида `a == b || c == d`. Согласно Вашей логике (где приоритет логических ИЛИ выше, чем у знака равенства) они бы преобразовались в `a == (b || c) == d`

Comment: @AivanF.Упс, действительно, напутал. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете сравнивать значение одной переменной сразу с несколькими значениями. Вам нужно сравнить значение с каждым из них. Пример:

Неправильно: `a==b||c`

Правильно: `a==b||a==c`

Есть такой вариант сравнения: `[b,c].indexOf(a)+1`

Answer (score 3):

По большому счету все гораздо проще:

```js
const countVowels = (w) => {
  return w.match(/[aeiou]/g).reduce((a, v) => {
    a[v] = a[v] === undefined ? 1 : a[v] += 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log(countVowels('abracadabra'));
console.log(countVowels('abcdu'));
console.log(countVowels('this code is fantastic, isn\'t it?'));
```

Comment: Эммм.. Вы уверены что это подходит?

Comment: @LazyTechwork, желаете сказать "нет"?

Comment: Это тоже вариант решения (автором не было сказано, что нужно сделать исключительно с помощью логических операторов). От меня +1

Comment: надо было еще сократить имена переменных ..чтобы ухудшить код еще .

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, а что же вам мешает блеснуть эрудицией и написать идеальный с вашей точки зрения код?

Answer (score 2):

Это так не работает. Потому что логические операторы, упрощённо говоря, являются функциями от двух аргументов со значениями `true` / `false`. Они не работают с другими типами, со списками возможных совпадений. Мысленно представьте их как функции `or(x, y)`, `and(x, y)`, где x и y – булевые значения.

Используя такую нотацию логическое ИЛИ запишется так:

```
or(or(array[s] === "a"), equal(array[s] === "e")), equalarray[s] === "i"))
// и ещё несколько слоёв or
```

В итоге, код на JavaScript'e должен быть не такой:

```
array[s] === "a" ||"e" ||"I" ...
```

А такой:

```
array[s] === "a" || array[s] === "e" || array[s] === "i" ...
```